# Finding alternative solutions to Bezout's Identity

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Here's question I'm really struggling with:

[image]

So far I believe I have found $d=21$ and $x=-2$ and $y=5$.

From here I'm unsure where to go as part b is making very little sense, could someone explain a way to go about it?

I have used standard trial and error to find more pairs of integers that satisfy the identity as it asked in b(i), however I wonder if there is a mathematical solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

What you did for part **a** is correct.

Now, part **b** is just to prove that the numbers $-2+105k$ and $5-252k$ are also solutions, for each $k\in\mathbb N$. And whoever created the problem asked you to prove this assertion by induction (a silly idea, in my humble opinion).